# How to solve "network is not ready: runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady" on GKE?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

[image: Network is not ready error]

This happen's once or twice a week, without apply any commands. I just receive the alert that many of pods are down.

The settings of the cluster, created at least 40 days ago:

```
gcloud container \
  clusters create "yourclustername" \
  --project "yourprojectname" \
  --zone "yourregion-zone" \
  --no-enable-basic-auth \
  --release-channel "regular" \
  --machine-type "e2-standard-2" \
  --image-type "COS" \
  --disk-type "pd-ssd" \
  --disk-size "20" \
  --metadata disable-legacy-endpoints=true \
  --scopes "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append" \
  --num-nodes "2" \
  --enable-stackdriver-kubernetes \
  --enable-ip-alias \
  --network "projects/yourprojectname/global/networks/yournetwork" \
  --subnetwork "projects/yourprojectname/regions/yourregion/subnetworks/yournetwork" \
  --default-max-pods-per-node "110" \
  --enable-autoscaling \
  --min-nodes "2" \
  --max-nodes "4" \
  --no-enable-master-authorized-networks \
  --addons HorizontalPodAutoscaling,HttpLoadBalancing,NodeLocalDNS,ApplicationManager \
  --enable-autoupgrade \
  --enable-autorepair \
  --max-surge-upgrade 1 \
  --max-unavailable-upgrade 0 \
  --enable-shielded-nodes
```

Node condition:

[image: node condition]

I delete the pods with this error and GKE creates another, off course this is not a solution, at least 4 minutes of downtime. How to solve this? Do I need something like calico or flannel even on GKE?

Comment: Yes, you need a network plugin for your cluster.

Comment: Related: [KUBEADM-1031](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1031) - Fixed with ''' kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml '''

Comment: Hello, did you tried applying the fix recommended by Iñigo? let us know!

Comment: Hello @willrof, I enabled Calico today (https://docs.projectcalico.org/getting-started/kubernetes/managed-public-cloud/gke) because GKE has a built in support for it (https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/network-policy). We will see in this week if everything stay ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, [I enabled Calico](https://docs.projectcalico.org/getting-started/kubernetes/managed-public-cloud/gke) and it's CNI plugin solved the problem. GKE has built in support for it and the steps to enable it can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/network-policy